# Camera2 resolutions - "outputSizes must not be null" or "At least one stream configuration for IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED must exist"

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have a few devices reported by Crashlytics that they cannot return supported resolutions when using Camera2 API.

All reported devices runs Android 10

4 reported devices: Samsung Galaxy Note10+, Galaxy S20+, LG V60 ThinQ, sprd ums512_1h10_Natv (some noname device)

Errors like:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError
At least one stream configuration for IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED must exist
```

and

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
outputSizes must not be null
```

Method where it crashes

```
fun getRecordingResolutions(context: Context, cameraId: String): List<Size> {
    val characteristics = getCameraCharacteristics(context, cameraId)
    val map = characteristics.get(
        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP
    )!!
    val outputSizes = map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder::class.java)
    return outputSizes.toList()
}
```

How is that possible?

Firebase Crashlytics screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you found a fix for this?